# Find a vector orthogonal to both $u $and $j+k$

Tags: vectors

So, $u=i-3j+2k$

I understand how to solve these type of problems with two given vectors, however I am lost on this.

How do I find a vector orthogonal to both $u$ and $j+k$?

Comment: If you let $\mathbf{v=j+k}$, you have two given vectors, don't you?

Comment: No I have been given possible vectors; (-5i+j+k),(-5i-j+k),(i+5j+k),(i-5j+k)

Comment: You have two vectors. One of them is $i-3j+2k$; the other is $j+k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v = (a,b,c)$ such that $v \perp u$, and $v \perp j+k = (0,1,1) \Rightarrow a - 3b + 2c = 0 = b + c \Rightarrow a = -5c, b = -c \Rightarrow v = (-5c,-c,c) = c(-5,-1,1), c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $u=\langle 1,-3,2\rangle$ and $v=\langle 0,1,1\rangle$, then $u \times v=\langle-5,-1,1\rangle$ is orthogonal to both u and v.